# Facing url redirect issue

Tags: url, redirect, directory, dns

hi there i am using wordpress on main domain and mybb forum script on subdomain

now problem is this

when i point to site.com/forum/

the index.php file open up the forum with wrong urls

but my real url is subdoamin.site.com/index.php

how can i fix that

also getting this in error log

site.com/forum/thread title

istead of subdomain.site.com/thread title

using apache and cpanel

if one you have some time to check my problem please check it and help me i am very thank full to you if it fixed as i asked wordpress, mybb and also hoster to check and fix but no luck yet so please help me

thanks in advance
here is my url
asf-mobiles.com
and forums.asf-mobiles.com

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do a permanent redirect if you wish to specify a certain url to get redirected.

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^asf\-mobiles\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.asf\-mobiles\.com$
RewriteRule ^forums\/index\.php\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/forums\.asf\-mobiles\.com\/index\.php$1" [R=301,L]

Comment: i used this in htaccess but same issue

Comment: how to redirect  http://asf-mobiles.com/forums/Thread-Download-Belle-Shell-1-1-for-Symbian-Symbian-3-Anna-Belle  to http://asfmobiles.com/Thread-Download-Belle-Shell-1-1-for-Symbian-Symbian-3-Anna-Belle